# Java EE capabilities into Eclipse-Classic or Flex Builder 4.6

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, flexbuilder

There is a Flex lib which only compiles within FB4.6.
I tried using FB4.6 Eclipse plugin, but It doesn't compile within Eclipse 3.6.x or 3.7.

So I installed Java EE plugins (not exactly sure) into FB4.6.
But it doesn't give exact Java EE capabilities within FB4.6 (It doesn't behave as Eclipse-Java EE). 
For example I couldn't install the JSP editor.

Is there a way to upgrade FB4.6 to Java EE?

OR

Eclipse-Classic to Eclipse-Java EE?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to download Java EE and then install the Flash Builder plugin into it. Are you sure you are not downloading the 64-bit version of Java EE? Flash Builder plugin only supports 32-bit. Can you install the plugin into the regular version of 3.6, 3.7?